# Spread 'sed' command over multiple lines

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to spread one sed command over several lines in a bash file. I have multiple patterns that sed checks for and I am hoping to separate some of the patterns by a line change. Here is my current script that does not work, putting everything on one line works but I was hoping to just clean it up a bit and split things up.

```
#!/bin/sh -f

#files=$(ls -1 | egrep '.avi|.mkv');

#echo $files
for f in *.mkv *.avi;
 do
  renF=`echo $f | tr '.' ' ' | sed -e 's/ \([^ ]*\)$/.\1/; s/\ \[sharethefiles\ com\]//i' \
  -e 's/\ x264\-Ctu//i; s/\ x264\-Bia//i; s/\ x264\-Fov//i' \
  -e 's/\ Xvid\-Lol//i; s/\ Xvid\-Xor//i; s/\ Xvid\-Notv//i; s/\ Xvid\-Fqm//i; s/\ Xvid\-p0w4//i; Xvid\-BIA//i; s/\ Xvid\-Chgrp//i; s/\ Xvid\-Fov//i' \
  -e 's/\ PDTV\-Fov//i; s/\ PDTV\-River//i; s/\ PDTV\-Sfm' \
  -e 's/\ Dts\-Chd//i; s/\ WEB\-DL//i; s/\ H264\-SURFER//i' \
  -e 's/\ Dsr//; s/\ WS//i; s/\ PDTV//i; s/\ X264//i; s/\ Blu\-Ray//; s/\ Bdrip//i; s/\ Bluray//i; s/\ HDTV//i; s/\ DTS//i; s/\ AC3//i; s/\ Dd5//i; s/\ Dualaudio//i; s/\ AAC2//i; s/\ XVID//i'`
  #echo $renF
  if [ "$f" == "$renF" ]; then
        echo "FileName already cleaned."
  else
        mv "$f" "$renF"
  fi
 done
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you get an error message? What is it? Does the output differ from what you expect? In what way? It shouldn't be necessary to escape the spaces and hyphens the way you have.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
-e 's/\ Xvid\-Lol//i; s/\ Xvid\-Xor//i; s/\ Xvid\-Notv//i; s/\ Xvid\-Fqm//i; s/\ Xvid\-p0w4//i; Xvid\-BIA//i; s/\ Xvid\-Chgrp//i; s/\ Xvid\-Fov//i' \
```

There's a missing `s/`. It should be:

```
-e 's/\ Xvid\-Lol//i; s/\ Xvid\-Xor//i; s/\ Xvid\-Notv//i; s/\ Xvid\-Fqm//i; s/\ Xvid\-p0w4//i; s/\ Xvid\-BIA//i; s/\ Xvid\-Chgrp//i; s/\ Xvid\-Fov//i' \
```

I included the backslash for consistency.

This line is missing `//i`:

```
-e 's/\ PDTV\-Fov//i; s/\ PDTV\-River//i; s/\ PDTV\-Sfm
```

Corrected:

```
-e 's/\ PDTV\-Fov//i; s/\ PDTV\-River//i; s/\ PDTV\-Sfm//i
```

The error messages I got were what led me to the source of the errors:

```
sed: -e expression #3, char 93: unknown command: `X'
```

and

```
sed: -e expression #4, char 51: unterminated `s' command
```

Here's a suggestion on how to make this more readable and maintainable:

```
while read -r pattern
do
    sedscript+="$pattern;"
done <<EOF
s/ \([^ ]*\)$/.\1/
s/\ \[sharethefiles\ com\]//i
s/\ x264\-Ctu//i
s/\ x264\-Bia//i
...
s/\ XVID//i
EOF

renF=$(echo "$f" | tr '.' ' ' | sed -e "$sedscript")
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I understood you, but you can do something like this if you just want to have multiple lines of sed expressions:

```
v=`echo 123|sed 's/1/2/
s/2/3/
s/3/4/'`; echo $v
```

This displays `423`, as expected.

If you want it on one line, that's possible, too:

```
v=`echo 123|sed 's/1/2/ ; s/2/3/ ; s/3/4/'`; echo $v
```

gives the same result.

For what I see, I would actually suggest doing it in multiple lines as you are already doing, just putting every -e on a separate line, as I think that is more readable. Something like:

```
v=`echo 123|sed \
   -e 's/1/2/' \
   -e 's/2/3/' \
   -e 's/3/4/'`
echo $v
```

Check this link for more information:

- http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

under `Quoting multiple sed lines in the Bourne shell`

Comment: Well I was hoping to include the same commands on one line like:
sed -e 's/\ Xvid\-Lol//i; s/\ Xvid\-Xor//i; s/\ Xvid\-Notv//i AND use the semi-colon to separate similar patterns instead of splitting up each one individually. Trying to pair the patterns together if I can.

Answer (score 4):

A possibly nicer alternative would be to use a heredoc, if GNU sed is available (not built into OSX):

```
sed -f - "$IN" > "$OUT" << SED_SCRIPT
  s/a/1/g
  s/test/full/g
SED_SCRIPT
```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45591/using-a-here-doc-for-sed-and-a-file