# What is the "/i" flag in sed?

Tags: shell, sed

In `sed`, you can end a command with the flag `"/i"` (for example, see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198233/spread-sed-command-over-multiple-lines)). This seems to say "more sed commands coming," or something like that, so you can split sed commands in a script. Or maybe not— I can't find any documentation on this flag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a modifier to the regular expression which makes it case-insensitive. For instance, `s/\ XVID//i` would  replace `" xViD"` (or any other capitalization of those four letters) with nothing.

Comment: Ah, and in the documentation I was looking at it was shown with an uppercase I, which helped to confuse me.